# Any possibility to return an investment from scam smart contract?

Tags: smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, metamask, binance-smart-chain, bscscan

Recently I bought a token from pancakeswap. After a few hours I realized it was a scam - it's new, there are only buy operations, and no sell operations (almost).
Of course, I cannot swap it back (it's possible only via Dextools, but there is a Seel Tax 100%..; not possible via any other DeFi platform like UniSwap, 1inch, etc)

Below is the contract source code. If someone be able to help return this, I would be happy to share the money returned 50/50 (a few thousand $ with today's rate). Altough not sure it's possible.

Token link: https://bscscan.com/token/0xf166488da6010bf7dd6bc8f0ae33d77b76b29b4a#code

```
# Palkeoramix decompiler. 

const decimals = 18
const burnAddress = 57005

def storage:
  _balances is mapping of uint256 at storage 0
  unknown024c2ddd is mapping of uint256 at storage 1
  stor2 is mapping of uint8 at storage 2
  stor3 is mapping of uint8 at storage 3
  _totalSupply is uint256 at storage 4
  stor5 is array of struct at storage 5
  stor6 is array of struct at storage 6
  stor7 is uint8 at storage 7
  charityAddress is addr at storage 7 offset 8
  charityPercent is uint256 at storage 8
  unknown03807ee5 is uint256 at storage 9
  unknown360bfd54 is uint256 at storage 10
  burnAmount is uint256 at storage 11
  owner is addr at storage 12

def unknown024c2ddd(uint256 _param1, uint256 _param2) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 64
  require _param1 == addr(_param1)
  require _param2 == addr(_param2)
  return unknown024c2ddd[_param1][_param2]

def unknown03807ee5() payable: 
  return unknown03807ee5

def totalSupply() payable: 
  return _totalSupply

def unknown360bfd54() payable: 
  return unknown360bfd54

def _totalSupply() payable: 
  return _totalSupply

def burnAmount() payable: 
  return burnAmount

def charityPercent() payable: 
  return charityPercent

def _balances(address _param1) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 32
  require _param1 == _param1
  return _balances[_param1]

def balanceOf(address _owner) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 32
  require _owner == _owner
  return _balances[addr(_owner)]

def owner() payable: 
  return owner

def charityAddress() payable: 
  return charityAddress

def allowance(address _owner, address _spender) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 64
  require _owner == _owner
  require _spender == _spender
  return unknown024c2ddd[addr(_owner)][addr(_spender)]

#
#  Regular functions
#

def _fallback() payable: # default function
  revert

def unknownb81e05bc(uint256 _param1) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 32
  require caller == owner
  charityPercent = _param1

def unknownb64665af(uint256 _param1) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 32
  require caller == owner
  unknown03807ee5 = _param1

def changeOwner(address _newOwnerAddr) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 32
  require _newOwnerAddr == _newOwnerAddr
  require caller == owner
  owner = _newOwnerAddr

def unknownefbc27b5(uint256 _param1) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 32
  require _param1 == addr(_param1)
  require caller == owner
  owner = addr(_param1)

def unknowna3de4742(uint256 _param1) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 32
  require _param1 == addr(_param1)
  require caller == owner
  charityAddress = addr(_param1)

def unknowna1c6f281(uint256 _param1) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 32
  require _param1 == addr(_param1)
  require caller == owner
  stor3[addr(_param1)] = 0

def unknownd2f70975(uint256 _param1) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 32
  require _param1 == addr(_param1)
  require caller == owner
  stor3[addr(_param1)] = 1

def unknown661751f9(uint256 _param1, uint256 _param2) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 64
  require _param1 == addr(_param1)
  require _param2 == bool(_param2)
  require caller == owner
  stor7 = uint8(bool(_param2))
  return addr(_param1)

def burn(address _guy, uint256 _wad) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 64
  require _guy == _guy
  require caller == owner
  if not _guy:
      revert with 0, 'ERC20: burn to the zero address'
  if _totalSupply > !_wad:
      revert with 0, 17
  _totalSupply += _wad
  if _balances[addr(_guy)] > !_wad:
      revert with 0, 17
  _balances[addr(_guy)] += _wad
  log 0xfeddf252: _wad, 0, _guy

def approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 64
  require _spender == _spender
  if not caller:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve from the zero address'
  if not _spender:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve to the zero address'
  if not stor7:
      if not stor3[caller]:
          revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: transfer to the zero address'
  unknown024c2ddd[stor12][addr(_spender)] = _value
  log Approval(
        address tokenOwner=_value,
        address spender=owner,
        uint256 tokens=_spender)
  return 1

def increaseAllowance(address _spender, uint256 _addedValue) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 64
  require _spender == _spender
  if unknown024c2ddd[caller][addr(_spender)] > !_addedValue:
      revert with 0, 17
  if not caller:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve from the zero address'
  if not _spender:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve to the zero address'
  if not stor7:
      if not stor3[caller]:
          revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: transfer to the zero address'
  unknown024c2ddd[stor12][addr(_spender)] = unknown024c2ddd[caller][addr(_spender)] + _addedValue
  log Approval(
        address tokenOwner=(unknown024c2ddd[caller][addr(_spender)] + _addedValue),
        address spender=owner,
        uint256 tokens=_spender)
  return 1

def decreaseAllowance(address _spender, uint256 _subtractedValue) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 64
  require _spender == _spender
  if unknown024c2ddd[caller][addr(_spender)] < _subtractedValue:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: decreased allowance below zero'
  if not caller:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve from the zero address'
  if not _spender:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve to the zero address'
  if not stor7:
      if not stor3[caller]:
          revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: transfer to the zero address'
  unknown024c2ddd[stor12][addr(_spender)] = unknown024c2ddd[caller][addr(_spender)] - _subtractedValue
  log Approval(
        address tokenOwner=(unknown024c2ddd[caller][addr(_spender)] - _subtractedValue),
        address spender=owner,
        uint256 tokens=_spender)
  return 1

def transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 64
  require _to == _to
  if not caller:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: transfer from the zero address'
  require bool(stor2[caller]) != 1
  if not stor7:
      if not stor3[caller]:
          revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: transfer to the zero address'
  if _value and unknown03807ee5 > -1 / _value:
      revert with 0, 17
  if _value and charityPercent > -1 / _value:
      revert with 0, 17
  if _balances[caller] < _value:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance'
  _balances[caller] -= _value
  if _value < _value * charityPercent / 100:
      revert with 0, 17
  if _value - (_value * charityPercent / 100) < burnAmount:
      revert with 0, 17
  if _balances[addr(_to)] > !(_value - (_value * charityPercent / 100) - burnAmount):
      revert with 0, 17
  _balances[addr(_to)] = _balances[addr(_to)] + _value - (_value * charityPercent / 100) - burnAmount
  log 0xfeddf252: (_value - (_value * charityPercent / 100) - burnAmount), caller, _to
  if charityPercent:
      if _balances[addr(_to)] > !(_value * charityPercent / 100):
          revert with 0, 17
      _balances[addr(_to)] += _value * charityPercent / 100
      log 0xfeddf252: (_value * charityPercent / 100), caller, charityAddress
  if unknown03807ee5:
      if _totalSupply < _value * unknown03807ee5 / 100:
          revert with 0, 17
      _totalSupply -= _value * unknown03807ee5 / 100
      log 0xfeddf252: (_value * unknown03807ee5 / 100), caller, 57005
  return 1

def transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) payable: 
  require calldata.size - 4 >=ΓÇ▓ 96
  require _from == _from
  require _to == _to
  if not _from:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: transfer from the zero address'
  require bool(stor2[addr(_from)]) != 1
  if not stor7:
      if not stor3[addr(_from)]:
          revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: transfer to the zero address'
  if _value and unknown03807ee5 > -1 / _value:
      revert with 0, 17
  if _value and charityPercent > -1 / _value:
      revert with 0, 17
  if _balances[addr(_from)] < _value:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance'
  _balances[addr(_from)] -= _value
  if _value < _value * charityPercent / 100:
      revert with 0, 17
  if _value - (_value * charityPercent / 100) < burnAmount:
      revert with 0, 17
  if _balances[addr(_to)] > !(_value - (_value * charityPercent / 100) - burnAmount):
      revert with 0, 17
  _balances[addr(_to)] = _balances[addr(_to)] + _value - (_value * charityPercent / 100) - burnAmount
  log 0xfeddf252: (_value - (_value * charityPercent / 100) - burnAmount), _from, _to
  if charityPercent:
      if _balances[addr(_to)] > !(_value * charityPercent / 100):
          revert with 0, 17
      _balances[addr(_to)] += _value * charityPercent / 100
      log 0xfeddf252: (_value * charityPercent / 100), _from, charityAddress
  if unknown03807ee5:
      if _totalSupply < _value * unknown03807ee5 / 100:
          revert with 0, 17
      _totalSupply -= _value * unknown03807ee5 / 100
      log 0xfeddf252: (_value * unknown03807ee5 / 100), _from, 57005
  if unknown024c2ddd[addr(_from)][caller] < _value:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance'
  if not _from:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve from the zero address'
  if not caller:
      revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: approve to the zero address'
  if not stor7:
      if not stor3[caller]:
          revert with 0x8c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'ERC20: transfer to the zero address'
  unknown024c2ddd[stor12][caller] = unknown024c2ddd[addr(_from)][caller] - _value
  log Approval(
        address tokenOwner=(unknown024c2ddd[addr(_from)][caller] - _value),
        address spender=owner,
        uint256 tokens=caller)
  return 1

def name() payable: 
  if bool(stor5.length):
      if bool(stor5.length) == uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5 < 32:
          revert with 0, 34
      if bool(stor5.length):
          if bool(stor5.length) == uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5 < 32:
              revert with 0, 34
          if Mask(256, -1, stor5.length):
              if 31 < uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5:
                  mem[128] = uint256(stor5.field_0)
                  idx = 128
                  s = 0
                  while (uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5) + 96 > idx:
                      mem[idx + 32] = stor5[s].field_256
                      idx = idx + 32
                      s = s + 1
                      continue 
                  return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor5.length), data=mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)])
              mem[128] = 256 * stor5.length.field_8
      else:
          if bool(stor5.length) == stor5.length.field_1 < 32:
              revert with 0, 34
          if stor5.length.field_1:
              if 31 < stor5.length.field_1:
                  mem[128] = uint256(stor5.field_0)
                  idx = 128
                  s = 0
                  while stor5.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                      mem[idx + 32] = stor5[s].field_256
                      idx = idx + 32
                      s = s + 1
                      continue 
                  return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor5.length), data=mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)])
              mem[128] = 256 * stor5.length.field_8
      mem[ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5) + 192 len ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)] = mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)]
      if ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5) > uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5:
          mem[ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5) + (uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5) + 192] = 0
      return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor5.length), data=mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)], mem[(2 * ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)) + 192 len 2 * ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)]), 
  if bool(stor5.length) == stor5.length.field_1 < 32:
      revert with 0, 34
  if bool(stor5.length):
      if bool(stor5.length) == uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5 < 32:
          revert with 0, 34
      if Mask(256, -1, stor5.length):
          if 31 < uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5:
              mem[128] = uint256(stor5.field_0)
              idx = 128
              s = 0
              while (uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5) + 96 > idx:
                  mem[idx + 32] = stor5[s].field_256
                  idx = idx + 32
                  s = s + 1
                  continue 
              return Array(len=stor5.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)])
          mem[128] = 256 * stor5.length.field_8
  else:
      if bool(stor5.length) == stor5.length.field_1 < 32:
          revert with 0, 34
      if stor5.length.field_1:
          if 31 < stor5.length.field_1:
              mem[128] = uint256(stor5.field_0)
              idx = 128
              s = 0
              while stor5.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                  mem[idx + 32] = stor5[s].field_256
                  idx = idx + 32
                  s = s + 1
                  continue 
              return Array(len=stor5.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)])
          mem[128] = 256 * stor5.length.field_8
  mem[ceil32(stor5.length.field_1) + 192 len ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)] = mem[128 len ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)]
  if ceil32(stor5.length.field_1) > stor5.length.field_1:
      mem[ceil32(stor5.length.field_1) + stor5.length.field_1 + 192] = 0
  return Array(len=stor5.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)], mem[(2 * ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)) + 192 len 2 * ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)]), 

def _name() payable: 
  if bool(stor5.length):
      if bool(stor5.length) == uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5 < 32:
          revert with 0, 34
      if bool(stor5.length):
          if bool(stor5.length) == uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5 < 32:
              revert with 0, 34
          if Mask(256, -1, stor5.length):
              if 31 < uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5:
                  mem[128] = uint256(stor5.field_0)
                  idx = 128
                  s = 0
                  while (uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5) + 96 > idx:
                      mem[idx + 32] = stor5[s].field_256
                      idx = idx + 32
                      s = s + 1
                      continue 
                  return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor5.length), data=mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)])
              mem[128] = 256 * stor5.length.field_8
      else:
          if bool(stor5.length) == stor5.length.field_1 < 32:
              revert with 0, 34
          if stor5.length.field_1:
              if 31 < stor5.length.field_1:
                  mem[128] = uint256(stor5.field_0)
                  idx = 128
                  s = 0
                  while stor5.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                      mem[idx + 32] = stor5[s].field_256
                      idx = idx + 32
                      s = s + 1
                      continue 
                  return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor5.length), data=mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)])
              mem[128] = 256 * stor5.length.field_8
      mem[ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5) + 192 len ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)] = mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)]
      if ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5) > uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5:
          mem[ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5) + (uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5) + 192] = 0
      return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor5.length), data=mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)], mem[(2 * ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)) + 192 len 2 * ceil32(uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5)]), 
  if bool(stor5.length) == stor5.length.field_1 < 32:
      revert with 0, 34
  if bool(stor5.length):
      if bool(stor5.length) == uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5 < 32:
          revert with 0, 34
      if Mask(256, -1, stor5.length):
          if 31 < uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5:
              mem[128] = uint256(stor5.field_0)
              idx = 128
              s = 0
              while (uint255(stor5.length) * 0.5) + 96 > idx:
                  mem[idx + 32] = stor5[s].field_256
                  idx = idx + 32
                  s = s + 1
                  continue 
              return Array(len=stor5.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)])
          mem[128] = 256 * stor5.length.field_8
  else:
      if bool(stor5.length) == stor5.length.field_1 < 32:
          revert with 0, 34
      if stor5.length.field_1:
          if 31 < stor5.length.field_1:
              mem[128] = uint256(stor5.field_0)
              idx = 128
              s = 0
              while stor5.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                  mem[idx + 32] = stor5[s].field_256
                  idx = idx + 32
                  s = s + 1
                  continue 
              return Array(len=stor5.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)])
          mem[128] = 256 * stor5.length.field_8
  mem[ceil32(stor5.length.field_1) + 192 len ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)] = mem[128 len ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)]
  if ceil32(stor5.length.field_1) > stor5.length.field_1:
      mem[ceil32(stor5.length.field_1) + stor5.length.field_1 + 192] = 0
  return Array(len=stor5.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)], mem[(2 * ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)) + 192 len 2 * ceil32(stor5.length.field_1)]), 

def symbol() payable: 
  if bool(stor6.length):
      if bool(stor6.length) == uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5 < 32:
          revert with 0, 34
      if bool(stor6.length):
          if bool(stor6.length) == uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5 < 32:
              revert with 0, 34
          if Mask(256, -1, stor6.length):
              if 31 < uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5:
                  mem[128] = uint256(stor6.field_0)
                  idx = 128
                  s = 0
                  while (uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5) + 96 > idx:
                      mem[idx + 32] = stor6[s].field_256
                      idx = idx + 32
                      s = s + 1
                      continue 
                  return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor6.length), data=mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)])
              mem[128] = 256 * stor6.length.field_8
      else:
          if bool(stor6.length) == stor6.length.field_1 < 32:
              revert with 0, 34
          if stor6.length.field_1:
              if 31 < stor6.length.field_1:
                  mem[128] = uint256(stor6.field_0)
                  idx = 128
                  s = 0
                  while stor6.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                      mem[idx + 32] = stor6[s].field_256
                      idx = idx + 32
                      s = s + 1
                      continue 
                  return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor6.length), data=mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)])
              mem[128] = 256 * stor6.length.field_8
      mem[ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5) + 192 len ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)] = mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)]
      if ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5) > uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5:
          mem[ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5) + (uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5) + 192] = 0
      return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor6.length), data=mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)], mem[(2 * ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)) + 192 len 2 * ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)]), 
  if bool(stor6.length) == stor6.length.field_1 < 32:
      revert with 0, 34
  if bool(stor6.length):
      if bool(stor6.length) == uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5 < 32:
          revert with 0, 34
      if Mask(256, -1, stor6.length):
          if 31 < uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5:
              mem[128] = uint256(stor6.field_0)
              idx = 128
              s = 0
              while (uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5) + 96 > idx:
                  mem[idx + 32] = stor6[s].field_256
                  idx = idx + 32
                  s = s + 1
                  continue 
              return Array(len=stor6.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)])
          mem[128] = 256 * stor6.length.field_8
  else:
      if bool(stor6.length) == stor6.length.field_1 < 32:
          revert with 0, 34
      if stor6.length.field_1:
          if 31 < stor6.length.field_1:
              mem[128] = uint256(stor6.field_0)
              idx = 128
              s = 0
              while stor6.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                  mem[idx + 32] = stor6[s].field_256
                  idx = idx + 32
                  s = s + 1
                  continue 
              return Array(len=stor6.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)])
          mem[128] = 256 * stor6.length.field_8
  mem[ceil32(stor6.length.field_1) + 192 len ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)] = mem[128 len ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)]
  if ceil32(stor6.length.field_1) > stor6.length.field_1:
      mem[ceil32(stor6.length.field_1) + stor6.length.field_1 + 192] = 0
  return Array(len=stor6.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)], mem[(2 * ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)) + 192 len 2 * ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)]), 

def _symbol() payable: 
  if bool(stor6.length):
      if bool(stor6.length) == uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5 < 32:
          revert with 0, 34
      if bool(stor6.length):
          if bool(stor6.length) == uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5 < 32:
              revert with 0, 34
          if Mask(256, -1, stor6.length):
              if 31 < uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5:
                  mem[128] = uint256(stor6.field_0)
                  idx = 128
                  s = 0
                  while (uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5) + 96 > idx:
                      mem[idx + 32] = stor6[s].field_256
                      idx = idx + 32
                      s = s + 1
                      continue 
                  return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor6.length), data=mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)])
              mem[128] = 256 * stor6.length.field_8
      else:
          if bool(stor6.length) == stor6.length.field_1 < 32:
              revert with 0, 34
          if stor6.length.field_1:
              if 31 < stor6.length.field_1:
                  mem[128] = uint256(stor6.field_0)
                  idx = 128
                  s = 0
                  while stor6.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                      mem[idx + 32] = stor6[s].field_256
                      idx = idx + 32
                      s = s + 1
                      continue 
                  return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor6.length), data=mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)])
              mem[128] = 256 * stor6.length.field_8
      mem[ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5) + 192 len ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)] = mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)]
      if ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5) > uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5:
          mem[ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5) + (uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5) + 192] = 0
      return Array(len=2 * Mask(256, -1, stor6.length), data=mem[128 len ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)], mem[(2 * ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)) + 192 len 2 * ceil32(uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5)]), 
  if bool(stor6.length) == stor6.length.field_1 < 32:
      revert with 0, 34
  if bool(stor6.length):
      if bool(stor6.length) == uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5 < 32:
          revert with 0, 34
      if Mask(256, -1, stor6.length):
          if 31 < uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5:
              mem[128] = uint256(stor6.field_0)
              idx = 128
              s = 0
              while (uint255(stor6.length) * 0.5) + 96 > idx:
                  mem[idx + 32] = stor6[s].field_256
                  idx = idx + 32
                  s = s + 1
                  continue 
              return Array(len=stor6.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)])
          mem[128] = 256 * stor6.length.field_8
  else:
      if bool(stor6.length) == stor6.length.field_1 < 32:
          revert with 0, 34
      if stor6.length.field_1:
          if 31 < stor6.length.field_1:
              mem[128] = uint256(stor6.field_0)
              idx = 128
              s = 0
              while stor6.length.field_1 + 96 > idx:
                  mem[idx + 32] = stor6[s].field_256
                  idx = idx + 32
                  s = s + 1
                  continue 
              return Array(len=stor6.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)])
          mem[128] = 256 * stor6.length.field_8
  mem[ceil32(stor6.length.field_1) + 192 len ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)] = mem[128 len ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)]
  if ceil32(stor6.length.field_1) > stor6.length.field_1:
      mem[ceil32(stor6.length.field_1) + stor6.length.field_1 + 192] = 0
  return Array(len=stor6.length % 128, data=mem[128 len ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)], mem[(2 * ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)) + 192 len 2 * ceil32(stor6.length.field_1)]),
```

Expecting to return money or to be ensured that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Антон! Я в той же идиотской ситуации, по тому же смартконтракту и нашла твою запись))) я предлагаю объединить усилия, очень хочу восстановить справедливость! такая обидная импульсивная ошибка новичка, обиднее всего - через час понять, что всё в этом токене суперкриво...и наткнуться на блэклист при попытке свопа обратно (